# Git pull 403 "after" making repo private

Tags: github, ssh

So after Github gave all paid users unlimited private repos I went ahead and made many of my repos private.

Now when I try to pull changes on the remote server I get the following error.

> error: The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden while accessing
>   https://github.com/warmwhisky/contact.git/info/refs

I have SSH keys setup on both github and my server that are working fine with repos that have always been private.

If I change it back to public I can pull my changes with no errors.

What is the procedure to be able to go from a public repo to a private repo?